# Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am deploying a web app to heroku. But I'm getting an error that does not happen in local. MongoDB version: 3.6.3
The error thrown is:

```
2019-04-04T09:58:24.463888+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
2019-04-04T09:58:24.463889+00:00 app[web.1]: at _handle.close (net.js:597:12)
2019-04-04T09:58:24.473758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-04T09:58:24.474134+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-04T09:58:24.475302+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Quiniela@1.0.0 start: `node ./src/server.js`
2019-04-04T09:58:24.475457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-04T09:58:24.475782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-04T09:58:24.475903+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Quiniela@1.0.0 start script.
2019-04-04T09:58:24.476026+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-04T09:58:24.482952+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-04T09:58:24.483094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-04T09:58:24.483183+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-04T09_58_24_477Z-debug.log
2019-04-04T09:58:24.548590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-04T09:58:24.531532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-04T11:35:29.837751+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-04T11:35:48.925363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-04T11:35:50.613487+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-04T11:35:50.613511+00:00 app[web.1]: > Quiniela@1.0.0 start /app
2019-04-04T11:35:50.613513+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./src/server.js
2019-04-04T11:35:50.613514+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-04T11:35:51.950629+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-04-04T11:35:51.950664+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-04-04T11:35:51.950666+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-04-04T11:35:51.981763+00:00 app[web.1]: Server start in http://localhost: 30131
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150746+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:368
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150749+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150750+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150752+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150753+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150755+00:00 app[web.1]: at topology.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:412:16)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150759+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReplSet.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:364:11)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150760+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150762+00:00 app[web.1]: at ReplSet.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150767+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:631:23
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150769+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:357:9)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150770+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150771+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150772+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.cb (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:422:25)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:289:33)
2019-04-04T11:35:52.150775+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
```

I am using Node.js + Express and monogoose, connecting to MongoDB Atlas.

I'm not sure of the reason for the error. I have reviewed the routes, the mongoose models and the connection to the BD. But I do not find an origin of the problem

The code.
DB connect:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { mongodb } = require('./keys');
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  autoIndex: false, 
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
  reconnectInterval: 500, 
  poolSize: 10, 
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000, 
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, 
  family: 4 
};

// mongodb.URI: mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx-rbrmd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
connectTo=()=>{
  mongoose.connect(mongodb.URI, options)
    .then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err)));

}

connectTo()

module.exports = connectTo;
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const listEquipos = new Schema({
  nombreEquipo: String,
  thumbnail: String
});
const listaDeEquipos =mongoose.model('equipos_ligamx', listEquipos);

const partidos_pendientes_LigaMx = new Schema({
  equipoLocal: String,
  thumbnailLocal: String,
  equipoVisitante: String,
  thumbnailVisitante: String,
  fecha: String,
  hora: String
});
const partidosPendientesLigaMx = mongoose.model('partidos_pendientes_ligamx', partidos_pendientes_LigaMx);

const partidos_jugados_LigaMx = new Schema({
  equipoLocal: String,
  thumbnailLocal: String,
  equipoVisitante: String,
  thumbnailVisitante: String,
  year: String,
  resultado: String,
  ganador: String
});
const partidosJugadosLigaMx = mongoose.model('partidos_jugados_ligamx', partidos_jugados_LigaMx);

module.exports = {
  listaDeEquipos,
  partidosPendientesLigaMx,
  partidosJugadosLigaMx
}
```

And another file where I keep in BD:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { listEquiposLigaMx, partidosPendientesLigaMx, partidosJugadosLigaMx } = require('../../models/liga-mx')
var fs = require("fs");
var url = 'https://www.marca.com/claro-mx/futbol/liga-mx/clausura/calendario.html'

getPartidosPendientesLigaMx=()=>{

puppeteer.launch()
.then(async (browser) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    let equipo = await page.evaluate(()=>{

        const img_local = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.local figure img')
        ]

        const img_visitante = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.visitante figure img')
        ]

        const equipo_local = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.local span')
        ].map((equipoLocal)=> equipoLocal.innerText);

        const equipo_visitante = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.visitante span')
        ].map((equipoVisitante)=> equipoVisitante.innerText);

        const fecha = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.resultado .fecha')
        ].map((fecha)=> fecha.innerText);

        const hora = [
            ...document.querySelectorAll('.resultado .hora')
        ].map((hora)=> hora.innerText);
        const size = equipo_local.length;
        var resize = equipo_local.length-fecha.length-1;
        var indicador = -1;
        var date = new Date()
        var day = date.getDate()
        var month = date.getMonth()


        return equipo_local.map((item, index)=>{
            if(resize>index-1 && resize<img_local.length-1){
                resize++
                indicador++
                return(
                    ({
                        equipoLocal: img_local[resize].alt,
                        thumbnailLocal: img_local[resize].src,
                        equipoVisitante: img_visitante[resize].alt,
                        thumbnailVisitante: img_visitante[resize].src,
                        year: 2019,
                        fecha: fecha[indicador],
                        hora: hora[indicador]

                    })
                )
            }
        })
    })

    var equipoParse = equipo.filter(function (el) {
        return el != null;
      });

    partidosPendientesLigaMx.insertMany(equipoParse, function(err) {
        if (err) {console.log("El error papu: ",err)}
        console.log("Saved!")

    });
    await browser.close();
  }).
  catch((err)=> console.log('> Error: ', err))
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is.  You have a call to close on something that is not defined.  Without your code, no one will be able to offer any real help.  Look for calls to close and figure out why what you are calling it on is undefined.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is that I have reviewed each of the files and I can not find anything that could cause the error (I debugged and commented on the code). However, I will add the corresponding code.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1634

Comment: I have a version 3.6.3 of Mongo DB. So I do not think that's the problem.

Comment: The current driver version is 3.2.2. The version of the DB isn't the issue. What version of the driver are you using?

Comment: I get it. I have reviewed the package.json and the mongodb version is 3.2.2